# How to pass parameters to overridden scripts with sbt-native-packager?

Tags: linux, scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am using sbt-native-packager to build an RPM. I have some custom scripts for preInstall and postInstall as described [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/java_server/customize.html). Is there a way to pass parameters to these scripts from sbt?

Thanks

@mgosk thanks for the idea. I'm adding a comment here to be able to format it.

I can't seem to make it work. This is in my sbt file:

```
val appName = "myApp" + packageSuffix
bashScriptExtraDefines += s"appName=$appName"
```

This is my scriptlet:

```
${{template_declares}}
#start (or restart) the service
/etc/init.d/$appName restart
```

This is what get's generated in the rpm specs:

```
${{template_declares}}
#start (or restart) the service
/etc/init.d/$appName restart
```

It's exactly the same thing. No substitution. Am i missing something?

Comment: Which `sbt` ? From machine where you make package or target machine where you run app ?

Comment: From the machine where I create the package. I have some values computed by scala code that i need to insert in those scripts.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to define extra variable in `build.sbt`:

`bashScriptExtraDefines += s"""FOO=${sbtVariableHere}"""`

Next add line `${{template_declares}}` to your shell script. Native-packager template parser insert here `bashScriptDefines` and `bashScriptExtraDefines` that you define earlier.

There you have more info:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/cheatsheet.html#bash-script-src-templates-bash-template

http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/java_app/customize.html#more-complex-scripts